# Bootstrap bias of the sample correlation

Tags: correlation, bootstrap

I am working on a problem asking
"Provide a Bootstrap bias of $\hat{r}$ using R = 1000 bootstrap estimators." However, I am stuck on what even to do. As far as I know, the formula for finding bootstrap bias is

$Bias_{boot}(\hat{r}) = E[\hat{r}^\ast] - \hat{r} $

Please correct me if I am wrong. So from here, I used simple bootstrap function as

```
boot.fn = function (data, index) {
    X = data[index]
    Y = data[index]
    sample_cor_hat = cor(X, Y)
  return(sample_cor_hat)
}

b = boot(sample_distribution, boot.fn, R = 1000)
b
```

Then I would get

```
Bootstrap Statistics :
    original       bias     std. error
t1*        1 1.110223e-16 7.719711e-17
```

Is my formula for bias correct? am I using the correct way for the function?

update: here's the given data

```
sample_size = 20
sample_meanvector = c(2, 3)
sample_covariance_matrix = matrix(c(2, 0.4, 0.4, 1), ncol = 2)
sample_distribution = mvrnorm(n = sample_size, mu = sample_meanvector, Sigma = sample_covariance_matrix)
X = matrix(sample_distribution[,1])
Y = matrix(sample_distribution[,2])
```

Comment: X and Y are the same in your boot,fn function (aren't they?)

Comment: I am pretty new to stats so I might misunderstand something. I forgot to give more context, but I updated my post. @JeremyMiles

Comment: you can pretty much ignore my codes, sorry about the confusion. I guess my question is about the formula.

Comment: if your question is about the formula then the formula is correct. take the difference between the average of the 1000 bootstrap correlations and the true correlation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It  seems you are using a simple quantile style of
bootstrap. Perhaps it would be better to use bias-corrected
quantile bootstrap as below.

Roughly, each bootstrap
re-sample of the sample correlation is compared to the
observed sample correlation, and the distances `d.re` between
them are found. Then the boostrap CI is based on quantiles .025 and .975 of the $B$ `d.re`s.

For my fictitious normal data `x` and `y`, this bootstrap CI and the classical CI for population $\rho$ are essentially
both $(-0.14, 0.25.).$

```
# Fictitious normal data and classical CI
set.seed(2022)
x = rnorm(100, 50, 6)
y = rnorm(100, 50, 6)
r.obs = cor(x,y)
cor.test(x,y)$conf.int
[1] -0.1409677  0.2506400
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
plot(x, y, pch=19)
```

[image]

```
# 95% Nonparametric bootstrap CI
set.seed(1234)
B= 2000;  seq = 1:100;  d.re=numeric(B)
for (i in 1:B)  {
 seq.re = sample(seq, 100,rep=T)
 d.re[i] = cor(x[seq.re],y[seq.re]) - r.obs
 }
LR = quantile(d.re, c(.975,.025))
r.obs - LR 
     97.5%       2.5% 
-0.1387333  0.2473008
```

Then for non normal data,
the same bootstrap method provides a reasonable
95% CI for $\rho.$

```
set.seed(608)
x = rnorm(100, 50, 6) + 1:100
y = rnorm(100, 50, 6) + 1:100
r.obs = cor(x,y);  r.obs
[1] 0.9559053
plot(x, y, pch=19)
shapiro.test(x)$p.val
[1] 0.002321988       # Not normal
shapiro.test(y)$p.val
[1] 0.01022498        # Not normal
```

Because `x` and `y` are not normal one cannot rely
on the CI from `cor.test`; see end note. However, my bootstrap procedure should give useful CIs for samples as large as 100.

[image]

```
set.seed(1234)
B= 2000;  seq = 1:100;  d.re=numeric(B)
for (i in 1:B)  {
 seq.re = sample(seq, 100,rep=T)
 d.re[i] = cor(x[seq.re],y[seq.re]) - r.obs
 }
LR = quantile(d.re, c(.975,.025))
r.obs - LR
    97.5%      2.5% 
0.9412820 0.9751636
```

Note from R documentation for `cor.test`: "If method is 'pearson', the test statistic is based on Pearson's product moment correlation coefficient `cor(x, y)` and follows a t distribution with `length(x)-2` degrees of freedom *if the samples follow independent normal distributions.* [Emphasis added.]